# Proving that $\deg(fg) = \deg (f) \deg (g)$ for $f:S^1 \to S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to prove that $\deg(fg) = \deg (f) \deg (g)$ for $f:S^1 \to S^1$.

The intermediate step is proving that: if $a$ is a lift of $f \circ \exp$ and $b$ is a lift of $g \circ \exp$ then $a+b$ is a lift of $fg \circ \exp$, however I am having some problems.

To prove that $a+b$ is a lift of $fg \circ \exp$ I surely have to show that $(a+b) \circ \exp = fg \circ \exp$.

However I get that $$(a+b) \circ \exp (t) = a\circ \exp(t) + b\circ\exp(t)$$ 
$$ = f \circ \exp(t) + g \circ \exp(t)$$ $$ = (f+g)\circ \exp(t)$$

What's going wrong?

Comment: You have $f=e^a$ and $g=e^b$, so $fg=e^{a+b}$. Your composition is not in the correct order.

Comment: ah such a silly error! thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prove $\deg( f\circ g) = \deg(f) \deg(g) $?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298202/how-to-prove-deg-f-circ-g-degf-degg)